# Is there a definition freely available for the colorspace conversion from MEDIASUBTYPE_YUY2 to MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB24?

Tags: filter, directshow, converters, color-space

I'm currently looking to implement a directshow filter to convert the colorspace from the output of the standard SampleGrabber to the Video Mixing Renderer.  All of the video decoders I'm using output the MEDIASUBTYPE_YUY2 and I need to convert to MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB24.
Does anyone know of a freely available filter or definition of this conversion process?

Answer (score 0):

There is a filter in the standard DirectShow filters, which exactly does what you want (I can't remember the name right now, maybe AVI Decompressor ...).

Otherwise look at [FourCC.org](http://www.fourcc.org/) for a description of how the formats are formatted in memory.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately using the AVI Decompressor filter results in just one frame of video being rendered in my graph and then fails to render anymore.  Looked at Elecard, MediaLooks and MainConcept color space converters but all packaged as SDKs and very expensive seeing I just need the one conversion.
Will check FourCC.org.

Answer (score 0):

You can find conversion functions in open source FrameWave library:
http://framewave.sourceforge.net/Manual/aa_000_frames.html